# Supabase ANON API_KEY JWTs missing sub claim causing 401 error from auth API (https://<myinstance>.supabase.co/auth/v1/user)

Tags: oauth-2.0, supabase, nextjs-image, supabase-js

I'm using supabase-js client library to handle GitHub OAuth authentication in my nextjs 13 frontend app:

```js
// Login with GitHub
const { data, error } = await supabase.auth.signInWithOAuth({
  provider: 'github'
})
```

U nder the hood this is making an GET request to supabase's `/auth/v1/user` endpoint of my supabase instance with the supabase-provided api key already in the header.

This operation results in a 401 Unauthorized error:

```
GET https://<instance>.supabase.co/auth/v1/user 401 (Unauthorized)

{
  "error": "invalid claim: missing sub claim"  
}
```

[image: response tab in the network tab of browser]
[image: response tab in the network tab of browser]
[image: supabase.auth.getUser()]

The issue seems to be that the API_KEY JWT used by `signInWithOAuth()` is missing the expected `sub` claim, causing subsequent auth API requests to fail. But the weird thing this is the API key provided by supabase. Using both the `anon public` and `service_role secret` provided by supabase return this error for that endpoint. Both are JWTs that do not contain a `sub` field when decoded.

Debugging steps:

- Confirmed API_KEY works for non-auth REST endpoints like `/<not-user>/*`
- Verified OAuth flow returns valid GitHub access_token - which contains a sub field
- Checked for expiration or reuse issues
- I using managed free tier supabase and not a self-hosted or premium version.

Issues I have looked at:

- https://github.com/supabase/supabase/issues/13095
- https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/12400

Also, it appears in supabase the `gotrue` JWT encoding library may be involved according to this issue:

- https://github.com/supabase/gotrue/blob/4f5c2f6801c4fddd37cf6abbbd67eaa6897eb5cc/internal/api/auth.go#L90-L92

```golang
if claims.Subject == "" {
  return nil, unauthorizedError("invalid claim: missing sub claim")
}
```

This suggests the problem could lie in how Supabase encodes and signs JWTs returned by `signInWithOAuth()`, rather than the GitHub access token itself.

...

Any thoughts on why supabase would provide an API_KEY missing `sub` for OAuth and then go on to error out with a 401 when requested using the same API key?

Comment: Anon keys are not supposed to have `sub` claim. The error might be talking about the token obtained from Github. I would double check every steps you took to setup the Github app that is connected to your Supabase instance. https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/social-login/auth-github

Comment: Thanks @dshukertjr, I just went through those steps using new supabase api keys and new Github oauth app but I get the same error. The token from github does contain the "sub" claim when I decode it on jwt.io.

Comment: The error here is correct as the user isn't logged in at the time when `.getUser()` is being called. If this is from the NextJS template we've created it's due to the `.getUser()` call inside of the `app/page.tsx` file.

Comment: Oh, makes sense now. There has to be a session for `jwt` token to be available(or be created from) for `getUser` to request for user. @AndrewSmith Thanks